# VBA dropdown selection

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have a worksheet contain six columns, instead of use the Filter function from excel, I would like to create a dropdown menu that allows me to select the information from column A (strings) and then select information from colomn F (also string), how can I create that dropdown from VBA?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't fully clear to me in terms of what sort of functionality you want this drop-down menu to have, but you would be best off to investigate the following:

A) Developer Tab > Insert > List Box

You can specify a data range for this drop-down menu and link it to a cell which updates its value based on the drop-down list selection.

B) Data Tab > Data Validation > Allow: List

This allows you to select a list of data that you want to have appear in a particular cell.

Perhaps these would be useful for what you are looking to accomplish.